# Android View requires API level 14

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm getting the old "View requires API level 14 (current min is 8):   " error.  So I've read other similar questions and the most common answer for this error is to go into the manifest file and do this "uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />" which I did.

I downloaded the eclipse android plugin a couple days ago, and I'm quite certain I have ice cream sandwich so it should be able to to do a minSdk=14.  Anything else I can try?

Comment: The opening angle bracket "<" is not the problem.  For some reason the code wasn't showing up when I included it

Comment: try adding `targetSdkVersion` also.

Comment: that was originally there when i first started getting the error, so i deleted it to make mine more like what i was seeing online

Comment: It's good idea to have a target sdk version because it is the platform version against which you compile your app.

Comment: Sure, I just added it back in.  It doesn't seem to be making a difference though

Comment: Also, check out your project settings, make sure you are compiling against correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the error went away after I restarted eclipse and had the suggested target sdk version + minSdkVersion.  Not sure why the error didn't go away before I restarted eclipse, and not too happy with Eclipse at the moment....